# Java: Efficient way to create arrays from arraylists in chunks

Tags: java, arrays, performance, arraylist

I am not a native JAVA programmer. I am creating a client for an web service API. The API basically requires an array argument.

I am parsing an XML file, creating records and then using this API to make a bulk INSERT.

The problem is that that this API can only insert 200 records at once that means my array can only have 200 records or less at the time of making the call.

Since I do not know how many records in advance, I store my records in an ArrayList and later convert it into an Array using .ToArray()

```
APIObject[] invoiceArray = invoiceObjectlist.toArray(new APIObject[invoiceDetailObjectlist.size()]);
```

Now because of the 200 limit problem posed by the API, I need to create these arrays in chunks of 200 till all records in the ArrayList have been inserted.

Right now am thinking that I can loop through the array list and maintain a counter. When the counter = 200, I can create a new array and insert all elements to that point by maintaining index pointers or I can push elements into a new array list for every 200 records and convert that into an array and perform the insert.

What would be a better elegant/efficient method to do this in JAVA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<APIObject[]> chunks = new ArrayList<APIObject[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < bigList.size(); i += 200) {
  APIObject[] chunk = bigList.subList(i, Math.min(bigList.size(), i + 200))
    .toArray(new APIObject[200]);
  chunks.add(chunk);
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to reset the chucks list after each iteration?

Comment: Why would I?  The point of the chunks list is that you can just call up the API for each chunk.

Comment: Ok, than I'm definitely missing something. On the first iteration your add (should be addAll I think), adds the first 200 items to chunks. The second iteration, it adds the second 200, without removing the first, so the array now has 400 items. To array starts from the beggining of the list, so the exact same array from the first iteration will be "returned". Can you explain where my logic is failing?

Comment: Nope, it shouldn't be `addAll`.  On the first iteration we add an array containing the first 200 items to `chunks`.  On the next iteration we add a _completely new array_ containing the next 200 items to chunks.  `chunks` ends up being a list of _arrays_, each with size 200, and each containing a separate chunk.  I've rewritten the code a bit to make it slightly more obvious, though.

Comment: Ah geez the idiocy... I missed the fact that the list was of type APIObject[], and not APIObject... That teaches me to lay off stack overflow after midnight.

Comment: Thank you Loius. The subList() call is what I was looking for. Cool solution.